"skip function" doesn't skip a function
I'm trying to learn inner workings on Linux kernel. I want to record a detailed trace of what functions are executed, which will be processed by my scripts. Consider the following invocation of gdb:
( gdb -batch vmlinux \
-ex 'set architecture i386:x86-64' \
-ex 'target remote :1234' \
-ex 'break start_kernel' \
-ex 'break setup_boot_config' \
-ex 'break mm_init' \
-ex 'break ksys_write' \
-ex 'skip page_expected_state' \
-ex 'skip function  __free_pages_core' \
-ex 'skip function  __ClearPageReserved' \
-ex 'skip function  __clear_bit' \
-ex 'skip function  arch___clear_bit' \
-ex 'skip function  __free_pages_core' \
-ex 'skip function  set_page_count' \
-ex 'skip function  atomic_set' \
-ex 'skip function  arch_atomic_set' \
-ex 'skip function  check_free_page' \
-ex 'skip function  free_pages_prepare' \
-ex 'skip function  free_tail_pages_check' \
-ex 'source screencast-gdb.py' \
-ex 'quit' \
) 2>&1 | tee screencast-lower.log

And the following screencast-gdb.py:
import gdb

gdb.execute("cont")

while True:
    gdb.execute("step")
    if gdb.breakpoints() and gdb.execute("info breakpoints", to_string=True).find('*') != -1:
        break

Even though I explicitly ignored check_free_page, it still appears in the output:
> tail screencast-lower.log 
29              return __READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
1212            if (likely(page_expected_state(page, PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_FREE)))
free_pages_prepare (fpi_flags=0, check_free=true, order=0, page=0xc7f40000) at mm/page_alloc.c:1357
1357                            (page + i)->flags &= ~PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_PREP;
1350                    for (i = 1; i < (1 << order); i++) {
1351                            if (compound)
1353                            if (unlikely(check_free_page(page + i))) {
check_free_page (page=0xc7f46560) at ./arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h:29
29              return __READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
1212            if (likely(page_expected_state(page, PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_FREE)))

How can I force gdb to skip over it?
